# Symfony2 Form Splitting in sub forms with css helper

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, responsive-design, symfony-forms

I have large form, i need to split it in multiple form when on mobile view.

Desktop = 1 large form

Mobile = 2-3 smaller form, when i valid the 1 form, then new page 2 form, and so on..

I would like to do it in responsive way NOT sub-domaine like (http://mobile/blah.com)

PS: I want to avoid third party bundle !!

Advice, recommandation, direction anything than can help me

**My controller:**

```
public function  ownerRegisterAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $owner = new Owner();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($owner);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
    {   
        $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
            ->encodePassword($owner->getOwner(), $owner->getOwner()->getPassword());
        $owner->getOwner()->setPassword($password);
        $owner->getOwner()->setStatus('owner');
        $owner->getOwner()->setIsValid(0);
        $em->persist($owner);
        $em->flush();

        // Login users after registration 
        $this->get('apx_auth_after_register')->authenticateUser($tenant->getTenant());

        $response = $this->forward('PagesBundle:SearchOwner:search', ['owner' => $owner]);

        return $response;

    }

    return $this->render('::form/owner-register.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

**My Form Type :**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('corporate', CorporateType::class, ['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false, 'label' => false])
        //->add('postcode', NumberType::class,['label' => false])
        ->add('type', TypeType::class, ['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false,'label' => false])
        ->add('room', NbRoomType::class,['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false,'label' => false])
        ->add('rent', NumberType::class,['label' => false])
        ->add('area', NumberType::class,['label' => false])
        ->add('images', CollectionType::class, [
                            'entry_type' => ImagesFlatType::class,
                            'allow_add' => true,
                            'required' => false,
                            'allow_delete' => true,
                            'label' => false,
                            ])

        ->add('fee', NumberType::class, ['label' => false, 'required' => false])
        // to be defined in list  by city
        ->add('transport', TextType::class,['label' => false, 'required' => false])
        ->add('furnished', FurnishedType::class, ['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false,'label' => false])
        ->add('vip', LesVipType::class, ['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true,'label' => false])
        ->add('feature', FeatureType::class, ['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true,'label' => false])
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class,['label' => false, 'required' => false])

        // City ajax call to be fix 
        ->add('location', EntityType::class, ['label' => false,
                                            'class' => 'PagesBundle:City',
                                            'choice_label' => 'zone']);
```

Thanks all

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Without mobile subdomain and with css help only

When you use `FormBuilder::add()` you create an instance of FormType which can be :

- the entire form,
- a field,
- a sub form.

So they all behave the same way.

Then you can easily split your FormType in 3 **SubFormTypes** :

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

/*
 * When forms get heavy, it becomes handy to use aliases
 * on import use statements since it eases the reading in code
 * and reduces the list of imports.
 */
use Type as AppType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type as OrmType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type as CoreType;

// An abstract class which all sub form will extend.
abstract class AbstractSubFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /*
     * We need to add a submit button on the sub form
     * which will be only visible on mobile screens.
     *
     * Then to get help of css class :
     *  use ".submit-sub_owner { display: 'none'; }" for desktop screens,
     *  and ".submit-sub_owner { display: 'block'; }" for mobile screens.
     *
     * Plus we need dynamic hiding of next sub forms from controller :
     * use ".sub_owner-next { display: 'none'; }" for mobile screens.
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options = array())
    {
        $builder->add('submit', CoreType\SubmitType::class,
            'attr' => array(
                // Needed to target sub owner controller.
                'formaction' => $options['sub_action'],
                // Hides sub owners submit button on big screens.
                'class' => 'submit_sub_owner',
            )
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $subNextNormalizer = function (Options $options, $subNext) {
            $hideNextSubOwners = isset($options['sub_next']) && $subNext;
            // Sets "attr" option of this sub owner type.
            $options['attr']['class'] = $hideNextSubOwners ? 'sub_owner-next' : '';
        }

        // Allows custom options.
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('sub_action' => '', 'sub_next' => false));

        // Hides sub owners exept the first stage from main controller.
        $resolver->setNormalizer('sub_next', $subNextNormalizer);
    }
}

// Stage 1
class SubOwnerOne extends AppType\AbstractSubFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options = array())
    {
        // Arbitrary cut of your example
        $builder
            ->add('corporate', AppType\CorporateType::class)
            ->add('type', AppType\TypeType::class)
            ->add('room', AppType\NbRoomType::class);

        // Call parent to optionnaly add sumbit button
        parent::builForm($builder, $options);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sub_owner_1';
    }
}

// Stage 2
// note that this one is tricky because there is an image that may be a file.
class SubOwnerTwo extends AppType\AbstractSubFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options = array())
    {
        // Arbitrary cut of your example
        $builder
            //->add('postcode')
            ->add('area')
            ->add('rent')
            ->add('images', CoreType\CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => AppType\ImagesFlatType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ));

        // Call parent to optionnaly add sumbit button
        parent::builForm($builder, $options);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefault('data_class', CoreType\NumberType::class);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sub_owner_2';
    }
}

// Last stage
class SubOwnerThree extends AppType\AbstractSubFormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options = array())
    {
        // Arbitrary cut of your example
        $builder
            ->add('fee', CoreType\NumberType::class, array('required' => false))
            // to be defined in list by city
            ->add('transport', CoreType\TextType::class, array('required' => false))
            ->add('furnished', AppType\FurnishedType::class) // define options in class
            ->add('vip', AppType\LesVipType::class)          // when belongs to AppType
            ->add('feature', AppType\FeatureType::class)     // ...
            ->add('description', CoreType\TextareaType::class, array('required' => false))
            // City ajax call to be fix
            ->add('location', OrmType\EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'PagesBundle:City',
                'choice_label' => 'zone',
            ));

        // Call parent to optionnaly add sumbit button
        parent::builForm($builder, $options);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sub_owner_3';
    }
}
```

One **FormType** to wrap them all :

```
class OwnerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function createForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options = array())
    {
        $sub = isset($option['sub_action']) ? $options['sub_action'] : false;
        $next = isset($option['sub_next']) ? $options['sub_next'] : false;

        $builder
            ->add('stage_one', AppType\SubOwnerOne::class, array(
                'sub_action' => $sub, // get form action from controllers.
            ))
            ->add('stage_two', AppType\SubOwnerTwo::class, array(
                'sub_action' => $sub,
                'sub_next' => $next, // hide sub owners from main controller on mobile screens.
            ))
            ->add('final', AppType\SubFormTypeThree::class, array(
                'sub_action' => $sub,
                'sub_next' => $next,
            ))
            ->add('submit', CoreType\SubmitType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    // Allows using ".submit-owner { display: 'none'; }" for mobile screens.
                    'class' => 'submit-owner',
                ),
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'label' => false,
             // Allows custom options
            'sub_action' => '',
            'sub_next' => false,
        ));
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Controllers** :

```
// Holds two controllers, one for owner type and another for sub owner types.
class OwnerController extends \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
{
    /*
     * Main controller.
     *
     * This handles initial request
     * and renders a view with a form view of OwnerType
     */
    public function  ownerRegisterAction(Request $request)
    {
        $owner = new Owner();

        // Customizes options
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($owner, array(
            // Uses route name of the other controller
            'sub_action' => $this->generateUrl('handle_sub_owners'),
            // Hides next stages
            'sub_next' => true,
        ))->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted && $form->isValid()) {
            $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
                ->encodePassword($owner->getOwner(), $owner->getOwner()->getPassword());
            $owner->getOwner()->setPassword($password);
            $owner->getOwner()->setStatus('owner');
            $owner->getOwner()->setIsValid(0);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($owner);
            $em->flush();

            // Login users after registration
            $this->get('apx_auth_after_register')->authenticateUser($tenant->getTenant());

            // Forwards quiting registration process
            return $this->forward('PagesBundle:SearchOwner:search', array('owner' => $owner));
        }

        // This view should use css rules from above comments
        return $this->render('::form/owner-register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Secondary controller handles sub forms
    * and renders one form view among the sub forms.
    *
    * @Route('/_sub_owners', name="handle_sub_owners")
    */
    public function handleSubOwnersAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Customize sub form action
        $action = array('sub_action' => $this->generateUrl('handle_sub_owners'));
        // Option "sub_next" will default to false.

        $form = $this->createForm(AppType\OwnerType::class, new Owner(), $action);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $subOwner1 = $form->get('stage_one');
        $subOwner2 = $form->get('stage_two');
        $finalOwner = $form->get('final');

        // Last stage is done, reforwards to the main controller.
        if ($finalOwner->isSubmitted() && $finalOwner->isValid()) {
            // Submits $data to new OwnerType as $form has been submitted by "handleRequest()" call
            $owner = $this->createForm(AppType\OwnerType::class, new Owner());
            $owner->get('stage_one')->submit(json_decode($finalOwner->get('j_stage_one')->getData()));
            $owner->get('stage_two')->submit(json_decode($finalOwner->get('j_stage_two')->getData()));
            $owner->get('final')->submit($finalOwner->getData());

            // Form in main controller will handle the request again,
            // so we need to pass normalized data.
            return $this->forward('App:Owner:ownerRegister', array(), $owner->getNormData())
        }

        // Stage 2 is done
        if ($subOwner2->isSubmitted() && $subOwner2->isValid()) {
            // Gets back json of stage 1
            $finalOwner->add('j_stage_one', 'hidden', array(
                // Unmaps this hidden field as it won't match any property of Owner
                'mapped' => false,
                'data' => $subOwner1->get('j_stage_1')->getData(),
            ));
            // Saves json of stage 2
            $finalOwner->add('j_stage_two', 'hidden', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'data' => json_encode($subOwner2->getData(), true),
            ));

            // Renders final stage
            return $this->render('::form/owner-register.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $finalOwner->createView(),
            ));
        }

        // Stage 1 is done
        if ($subOwner1->isSubmitted() && $subOwner1->isValid()) {
            // Save json of $subOwner1
            $subOwner2->add('j_stage_one', 'hidden', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'data' => json_encode($subOwner1->getData(), true),
            ));

            // Render stage 2
            return $this->render('::form/owner-register.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $subOwner2->createView(),
            ));
        }

        // Else renders stage 1
        return $this->render('::form/owner-register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $subOwner1->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

**View**

```
{# ::form/owner-register.html.twig #}
...
<style type="text/css">
    /* @media mobile screens */
    .sub_owner-next, .submit-owner { display: 'none'; }
    .submit-sub_owner { display: 'block'; }

    /* @media desktop screens */
    .submit-sub_owner { display: 'none'; }
</style>
...
{{ form_start(form) }}
{% form sub_form in form %}
    {{ form_start(sub_form) }}
    {{ form_widget(sub_form) }}
    {{ form_end(sub_form) }}
{% endear %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
...
```

### Alternative use Mobile Detection

There are many php libraries to detect mobile browsers.

For example https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect
which provides a bundle for symfony :
https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle

So you can even use a helper in a previous implementation :

```
$mobileDetector = $this->get('mobile_detect.mobile_detector');
$mobileDetector->isMobile();
$mobileDetector->isTablet()
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this soon

Comment: @Nicks made some edits to my answer, waiting for your feedback once tested ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think it is a hard task. Actually it's seems somewhat obvious (at least for me though).

You could to use something like **TabView** or **Accordion-like** view. All of this can be achieved by using pure CSS (and maybe Javascript).

As you can see it is not related to Symfony at all. By using CSS + Media-queries I'm sure you can get done the desired UI.

Comment: From desktop large from, i still don't get how can i split it in 2 or 3 pages on mobile view and course i need to thing about 2 or 3 validation process instead of only one in desktop view.

Comment: @Nicks The form rendering can be splitted along from twig template. Regard to validation youl coud to use Validation Groups (see the docs) or create something like ValidatorService and call via XHR.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split form using responsive way, you should format form output in your view (e.g. TWIG file). Place form parts in separate containers and then use CSS media queries and JS. Good luck!

Comment: I don't know JS/Jquery, so i start learning this a little and  i can do this by playing with addClass - removeClass hide show etc... I don't know if this is the best way to do but it pretty easy to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I did something a few years back in which a passed a 'step' var into the formType which I incremented after each post.

I used an if statement in the formType to build the form depending on the step value.